# Javascript function to submit parametric form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have many forms in a webpage.
Form id is given by php like:

```
<FORM method="post" id="<?php echo $idform;?>">
```

In every form the submit button is:

```
<input name="inoltro" value="Book" type="button" onclick="mySubmit(<?php echo $idform;?>)">
```

Submit function is:

```
function mySubmit(FormToSubmit)
{
    show_message();
    document.getElementById(FormToSubmit).submit();
}
```

Console javascritp error says it cannot submit null form.

Where am I wrong?

many thanks for your kind help

Comment: Is that really your code? The onclick code becomes something like `onclick="mySubmit(myForm"` with a missing closing bracket which should throw a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry @JJJ, type error. 
Now corrected.

Comment: Try putting single quotes around the form's ID in your `onclick` like so: `onclick="mySubmit('<?php echo $idform;?>')"` - I have a feeling the PHP `echo` is producing the form's ID without any quotation marks, and so your function is taking `FormToSubmit` as a null variable instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get form object in `on*` events by passing `this.form` as a parameter.

Just like that:

```js
function mySubmit(form) {
  console.log(form);
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="?">
 <input type="text" name="test">
 <input type="button" name="inoltro" value="Book" onclick="mySubmit(this.form)">
</form>
```

Press `Ctrl+Shift+J` in Chrome to see developer's console.

Comment: Just tried your solution. In console my form is printed correctly. But if I try to submit with "document.getElementById(form).submit();" it says: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null

Comment: No no no, form is not an ID, it is a DOM object. Try `form.submit()`

Comment: Yes @Albert221 you're is the correct solution. It works!

Answer (score 0):

The form you are trying to submit does not exist ...

please check again you are echoing correct values in id attribute of the form ...

```
onclick="mySubmit('<?php echo $idform;?>')"
```

make sure this code is outputting something ... use google chrome's inspect element to check the echoed values

Comment: Hi, code seems to be ok:  I think php code is ok, it prints out:
    <form action=​"/​crigest/​turni/​dett_generico.php?id=1525" method=​"post" id=​"ADD15255">

Comment: That's not the problem, it's where you're calling the function that you have an issue. See my comment on your question.